# How to set unique key in SQL Server 2005 .?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

How to set `unique key constraint` in SQL Server 2005? Not through script or query.

Comment: Do you mean an auto incrementing integer, or a unique identifer?

Comment: Question is not very clear? Can you explain what do you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In management studio table designer right click the table and choose "Indexes/Keys" from the popup menu.

Select the column(s) that comprise the key and choose "Unique Key" for the "Type" option.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

To add a unique key without scripting, follow these steps:

- Right click the table in question and select *Design*
- Right click the header of the table design and select *Indexes/Keys*
- In the window that appears, click *Add*
- In the properties window that appears, click the ellipsis (...) button next to the column names and select the columns that make up the unique key
- Change the type to *Unique Key*

Once you've done this, click close and save your table.

If you'd rather have a primary key, such as an auto incrementing integer

- Start a new table, or open the existing table in the table designer
- Add a column named what you want with the Data Type int
- Right click the column's row header and click "Set Primary Key"
- In the column properties window, expand the identity specification property
- Change (Is Identity) to Yes.

If you literally just want to set an existing column as a primary key:

- Open the table in Table Design (right-click > Design)
- Right click the column header and choose set key, or use the key button in the toolbar